# Creating A Random Iterator (Permutation)

Tags: c++, random, iterator, permutation

Last big hurdle for this project, and I hope you you guys can help me out because I am terribly stuck again. What I'm working on is a dynamically allocated templated container, with all the code written from scratch with a constant iterator, and a random iterator that generates a permutation in the form of an array of indices. Thus far I've gotten it to generate the indices properly, however I am unsure as to how to get the random iterator to move through them using that array of indices. I think it's a problem with my ++ operator for the random iterator, but I'm totally unsure of what to do make it iterate properly. Here are some snippets:

```
// Implementation of the rand_iterator method when provided a seed  by   
// the user. rand_iterator takes a pointer to a container object, and the seed // as parameters.
template <class T>
typename sorted<T>::rand_iterator sorted<T>::rndbegin(unsigned seed){
  return rand_iterator(this, seed);
}

// Implementation of the const iterator pre-incrementer.
template <class T>
typename sorted<T>::const_iterator sorted<T>::const_iterator::operator++(){ ++m_current; return *this; }


// This is what my rndbegin looks like at the moment.
// Implementation of the rand_iterator rndbegin method.
template <class T>
typename sorted<T>::rand_iterator sorted<T>::rndbegin(){
  sorted<T>::rand_iterator newrand(this);
  return newrand;
}

// Implementation of the non-default rand iterator constructor given 
// a user-defined seed.
template <class T>
sorted<T>::rand_iterator::rand_iterator(sorted<T>* srtdPtr, unsigned seed){

  int j;
  m_rsize = srtdPtr->m_size;

  // Set up the random seed.
  // Allocate memory for m_random.
  srand(seed);
  m_random = new int[m_rsize];

  // Fill the randomized array with values.
  for (int i = 0; i < srtdPtr->m_size; i++)
    m_random[i] = i;

  // Randomize the values.
  for (int i = 0; i < srtdPtr->m_size; i++){

    T temp;

    j = rand() % (srtdPtr->m_size);
    temp = m_random[i];
    m_random[i] = m_random[j];
    m_random[j] = temp;
  }

  // Just testing to make sure the random array
  // is set up properly; it is. 
  cout << "Random seed test:" << endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < srtdPtr->m_size; i++)
    cout << m_random[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;

  m_current = 0;
  m_randPtr = srtdPtr;
}

// Implementation of the dereference operator.
template <class T>
const T& sorted<T>::rand_iterator::operator*(){
  return m_randPtr->m_data[m_random[m_current]];
}

// Some code from main that's causing an issue.
// ritr3 was already created and tested.
sorted<int>::rand_iterator ritr5(ritr3);

cout << "Printing copy constructed random index array - should print: 5 16 1 7 9 17 7 4 6" << endl;
cout << "Actually prints: " << endl;
for (ritr5 = x.rndbegin(4242); ritr5 != x.rndend(); ritr5++)
  cout << *ritr5 << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `m_current` be the index into `m_crandom`, and let it change from `0` to `n`, then `m_crandom[m_current]` is going to be the shuffled index into the actual data array.

Here's an example showing the basic idea:

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47b28c0be0bcd027

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm not sure I know how to implement your suggestion though.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that I should just make m_current an int for the rand_iterator class instead of a pointer and that way when it increments I can use it to index across the array? That makes sense, I will try it.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: I understand now. However, the rand_iterator is a class within the templated container class, and m_data (which is the actual array containing the data) is a private member of the container class. So when I have the dereferencing operator return m_data[m_crandom[m_current]] I get an invalid use of nonstatic data member error.

Comment: This is actually not particular to your rand_iterator, any iterator will need to have a way to reference the container's data.

Comment: Right, that makes sense. The only way I can think of to do that with what I know is to allocate more memory to copy the m_data array from the container into a new array in the rand_iterator class so I can just output it from there. Without rand_iterator having a pointer to the spot in the array I'm not sure what other approach I can take.

Comment: I actually tried the method I outlined above. I print the values using the permuted indices from the new array in rand_iterator and that works. However when I try to use the dereference operator from main, it simply prints the permutation index array.

Comment: What does your dereference operator look like?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110866/discussion-between-luke-lee-and-swingonaspiral).